# After updating the record set the Screen must update

Tags: informix, 4gl

In informix 4gl(genero 4JS) how can I refresh the screen after updating the record set in the database?  Right now I can only update the record but the screen is not updating. I think I am missing something. The following set is working fine. after updating I need to refresh the screen with new status.

```
update person set
    person = m_folder.person,
    date = m_folder.date,
    time = m_folder.time,
    status = m_folder.status,
    userid = m_folder.userid,
where rowid = g_rowid
```

Answer (score 1):

After you've updated the database, your program must redisplay the data (possibly after fetching the updated values).  I4GL changes the screen when you DISPLAY to it (or INPUT from it); it changes the database when you execute SQL; it never automatically does one because you've done the other (which is actually good; it gives you control over everything).

Answer (score 0):

Try the `CALL ui.Interface.Refresh()` instruction.
If it doesn't work then Jonathan Leffler is right: you have to use some dialog-type instruction (DISPLAY or INPUT) to display it, like `DISPLAY BY NAME m_folder.*`